# Spring MVC - display and track user choice in an object containing multiple hierarchies

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I need help in the correct approach to follow for a particular scenario using `Spring MVC` -

From the service I get a Collection type. Now each category has fields like id, name, description and also a Collection available for that category.

Now I have to show a user registration form, where apart from the user fields (like Name, email, etc..), these various Category data needs to be presented. The user has the option to select a category and also a product out of the listed products for that category. So, I need to show a checkbox against the category name and then a combo box for displaying the products.

How can I capture this in the command object passed to `JSP`. I have created a command as UserForm where in apart from the user fields, I have a Collection also in that. I can iterate through that in `JSP`, but how to capture the user selections for the category and the product chosen for that category? 
Do I need to keep separate fields in the form to capture the user selections(e.g. int[] categoryId and int[] productId) or is there any way to do it?

Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can submit multiple object hierarchies in Spring MVC.

Let's say you have something like this :

```
public class UserForm {
    private List<Category> categories;
    ...
}

public class Category {
    private List<Product> products;
    private String name;
    ...
}

public class Product {
    private String name;
}
```

To submit the very first category name, you can do :

```
<form:input path="categories[0].name" />
```

To submit the very first product name, you can do :

```
<form:input path="categories[0].products[0].name" />
```

To submit multiple categories/products, replace 0 with an index that you would set on the server side (JSP) or on the Javascript side. Example of index set on the JSP :

```
<form:input path="categories[${someIndex}].name" />
```

Comment: Thanks Jerome, I am aware of capturing the user inputs as you mentioned, but my requirement is not to change any existing category or product, but to get the user selection. For example, I need to show a checkbox against each category and for the product list of category, I have to display a combobox. The user can show their interested category and product for that category by checking the category checkbox and selecting the product out of the combo box. How can this be implemented?

Comment: More to add- A general approach is to have two arrays to capture the user selection for Category and Product. e.g. boolean[] categorySelected and String[] productId. In the JSP, the cehckbox is path mapped to categorySelected and the combo box path is mapped to productId. This way, I can trap the user selections made on the screen. But, I wanted to know whether there is any other cleaner approach which can directly deal with category collection?